# Como carregar um SelectOneMenu com base no Select Anterior usando JSF?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando cadastrar um Bairro com Base na Cidade e o estado selecionado.

Sendo que, a lista da cidade, depende do estado selecionado.

Segue meu código:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <h:selectOneMenu id="selectCidade" class="form-control mr-3" value="#{bairroBean.cidade}" rendered="true" >
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Cidade" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{bairroBean.cidades}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.nome}" itemValue="#{c.id}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome" />
                <h:inputText type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Digite o nome da cidade"
                    value="#{cidadeBean.cidade.nome}" />
            </div>
```

Não sei como fazer isso usando JSF.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve criar uma função `onChange` no select do estado e, dentro dele, alterar a lista `cidades`, atualizando com as cidades do estado.

Por exemplo:

```
public void onChangeEstado() {
    this.cidades = (List<Cidade>) carregarCidadesPorEstado(this.estadoSelecionado);
}
```

Já no select do estado você deve adicionar as seguintes linhas:

```
<p:ajax
    update="selectCidade"
    event="change" process="selectEstado"
    listener="#{bairroBean.onChangeEstado}" />
```

Isso deve atualizar a cidade, conforme você selecionar estado.

Comment: Não sei o que esta acontecendo... esse serviço de change não ta entrando no método de jeito nenhum...

Comment: public void processaCidades() {
  System.out.println("onChangeEstado() -----------");
  System.out.println(estado);
     this.cidades = this.cidadeService.buscaPorEstado(estado);
 }

Comment: Veja se a minha alteração surte efeito pra ti. Lembrando que o bean do onChange deve ser onde está a lista de cidades...

Comment: É... não funcionou.... infelizmente... quer que eu atualize postando mais código?

Comment: Rapaz... consegui aqui... tive que fazer um EstadoConverter...

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver este problema, foi preciso definir uma Classe que implementa o Converter do Faces Framework.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Estado.class)
public class EstadoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
        Estado estado = new Estado();
        estado.setId(id);
        return estado;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Estado estado = (Estado) value;
        if (estado.getId() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return estado.getId().toString();
    }

}
```

A resposta anterior também tem relação com essa resposta. Mas, o Ajax não estava funcionando por falta dessa classe.